# SAS Proc Logistic Selection=Score

Tags: sas, selection, proc, logistic-regression, chi-squared

I'm using PROC LOGISTIC procedure in SAS and option SELECTION=SCORE which gives me few logistic regression models and their Chi-Square values. My question would be which model is better - with smaller Chi-Square or bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the larger chi-squared statistic will correspond with a lower p-value (more significance).  However, it is important to know the shape of the chi-squared distribution and also the number of degrees of freedom.  As you can see in the [graph](http://images.books24x7.com/bookimages/id_19477/fig371_02.jpg), the relationship between p and chi-squared changes based on the degrees of freedom.

Comment: oh yes, the p-value! Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

Score for Chi-Square  is larger, the model is better.